# Why aren't my Rails tests seeing the contents of my in-memory SQLite3 database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, sqlite

I'm trying to speed up the tests for a Rails application by using a SQLite3 in-memory database  as the test database for the app. I've followed the instructions in this [blog post](http://calicowebdev.com/2011/01/25/rails-3-sqlite-3-in-memory-databases/).

My database config in `database.yml` looks like this:

```
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: ":memory:"
  encoding: utf8
  verbosity: quiet
```

I also created the initializer as recommended:

```
def in_memory_database?
  Rails.env == "test" and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class == ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLiteAdapter ||
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class == ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter and
    Rails.configuration.database_configuration['test']['database'] == ':memory:'
end

if in_memory_database?
  ActiveRecord::Schema.verbose = false
  puts "creating sqlite in memory database"
  load "#{Rails.root}/db/schema.rb"
end
```

All of my tests fail because the fixtures cannot be loaded, as you can see:

```
creating sqlite in memory database
Loaded suite test/unit/vendor_appliance_test
Started
E
Finished in 0.070079 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_the_truth(VendorApplianceTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'advertisers'


1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors
```

The initializer does load the database (as you can see from the first line of the output), but for some reason the schema is not visible to the tests, either because it's looking in the wrong place or because it has been wiped by the time the tests start.

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this about shared connections:

http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/12/three-tips-to-improve-the-performance-of-your-test-suite/

sqllite maintains the in-memory db per connection. active record uses a connection pool and when you run the test it's using a different connection. you can check the object ids of the connections at various points to see the actual object changes.

if you share a single connection, you should get the behavior you expect.

and be faster to boot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just put the code below in test_helper.rb

```
def in_memory_database?
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class == ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLiteAdapter ||
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class == ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter and
    Rails.configuration.database_configuration['test']['database'] == ':memory:'
end

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
    if in_memory_database?
        ActiveRecord::Schema.verbose = false
        puts "creating sqlite in memory database"
        load "#{Rails.root}/db/schema.rb"
    end
end
```